# RxJS - What is the point of operators?

Tags: rxjs

What is the advantage of using RxJS operators such as *map* and *filter* as compared to simply performing the same operations on the values returned in the *subscribe* function? Is it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where you cannot perform everything synchronously. For example when you want to make a rest-call based on some emitted data and the work with the data emitted by the rest-call.

Or when you have 2 seperate streams, but there is a usecase where you need to execute them in order (maybe even based on each other), it is very easy to just chain those.

Also it makes testing a whole lot easier and more precise when you have very small functions with an input and output.

But as with everything: Just because a big company is using this, doesn't automatically mean that it makes sense for your small hobby-project to implement every last bit of what they are using on a project with multiple developers.

---

As for the performance: No, using rxjs-operators is **not** the fastest way of manipulating data but it offers a whole lot of other features (some of them mentioned above) that outweigh the (very small) impact this has on the performance. - If you are iterating through big arrays a couple times a second though, I'd suggest you to not use RxJS for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Some advantages

- Declarative
- Reusability

I mean if you subscribe in another place you will need to duplicate the same action that are in the subscribe. But if you declare the operators as part of the chain you will always perform the same way when it's called.